# Looking for learning resource regarding operator associativity and precedence for a parser that I am building

Tags: parsing, syntax, operators, operator-precedence, parboiled

I'm using [Parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/wiki) to build a parser for a search syntax that has several operators of varying precedence and associativity. As this will be my first parser, it would be really nice to see some good examples of how precedence and associativity are generally handled. In addition we have some unusual operators which don't appear to have associativity, similar to Python's ternary `<` operator (e.g. `a<b<c` => `(a<b)&&<b<c>`).

Can you direct me to good resources and examples regarding parsing operators of different associativity and precedence?

Comment: While this is not really an answer, the main tool Parboiled has for this is `FirstOf()`. This, and the fact that you can nest rules.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Calculator examples](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/tree/master/examples-java/src/main/java/org/parboiled/examples/calculators) for examples on how to do this.